# ChartJS Stacked Bar Chart Display Stack Names in Legend

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, legend, legend-properties

I have a stacked bar graph and wish to divide the data labels in the legend into groups based on the stack id/name to which they relate by including the stack id/name as header for each group of labels.

So imagine in structure:

```
datasets > label:'Apple'  > stack:'Fruit'
datasets > label:'Oranges' > stack:'Fruit'
datasets > label:'Bananas' > stack:'Fruit'
datasets > label:'Potato' > stack:'Vegetable'
datasets > label:'Pumpkin' > stack:'Vegetable'
datasets > label:'Squash' > stack:'Vegetable'
```

...and the desired legend displaying like...

```
Fruit
 Apple
 Oranges
 Bananas
Vegetables
 Potato
 Pumpkin
 Squash
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.